# How to get font size from shared preference to textView in recyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, font-size

I have two `recyclerView` Parent and Child, and in Settings I changed font size, and in Save Data Class I saved this size. How to get font size from shared preference in settings to section (Title Section) and items (Text Items)?

**1. In Parent Adapter:**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.viewDataBinding.section.text = list[position].section
        holder.viewDataBinding.childRv.apply {
            adapter = ChildAdapter(list[position].list)
        }
}
```

**2. In Child Adapter:**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChildAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.viewDataBinding.childText.text = list[position]
}
```

**3. In Activity:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
val mainBinding = binding.mainRecycler
        mainBinding.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@Activity)
            adapter = ParentAdapter(list)
        }
}
```

**4. in SaveData Class:**

```
class SaveData(context: Context) {
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences("file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

fun setFontSize(size: Float?) {
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putFloat("FontSize", size!!)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun loadFontSize(): Float {
        val size = sharedPreferences.getFloat("FontSize", 0f)
        return size
    }
}
```

Comment: You're already saving it and retrieving it.  You'd just use setTextSize on each UI element you wish it to apply to.  In a recyclerView, you'd probably do that in onBindViewHolder.  Although depending on what your app is doing with this, you may be better off just setting the text size in sp and allowing the user to scale it with text size at the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and get font when it is changed.